# Perl: Is it possible to subset a hash passing a value threshold?

Tags: perl, hash, subset, threshold

Say I have a hash of the form:

```
%hash = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 , d => 4 , e => 5 , f => 6 );
```

Can I obtain a subset of such hash passing a value threshold of 3, obtaining the following %subhash

```
%subhash = ( c => 3 , d => 4 , e => 5 , f => 6 );
```

and without having to enter a loop? Thanks

Comment: Be under no illusions - if you're iterating a data structure, you've got a loop. There is no solution to this. You cannot loop without looping. You can hide the fact you're doing so behind `map` or `grep` - but you cannot change the need to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.20+

```
%subhash = %hash{ grep $hash{$_} >= 3, keys %hash }
```

(though grep (and map) is still a loop)

Comment: Not just `grep`. There are four loops in there!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it, although a `map` implies a loop:

```
my %subhash = map {
                     $hash{$_} >= 3
                     ? ($_, $hash{$_})
                     : ()
                  } keys %hash;
```